# DropShadowEffect prevents display of QWebEngineView

Tags: pyqt, qwebengineview

I'm trying to display the content of a URL in a `QWebEngineView` element, which is inside a `QFrame` to which a `DropShadowEffect` is applied.

However, this effect apparently causes the `QWebEngineView` element to be unable to refresh the content and remains frozen.Since until some action is performed outside the focus of the interface, the `QWebEngineView` element updates its content

If I comment this line by removing the `DropShadowEffect`, `QWebEngineView` is displayed without any problem

```
self.shadow_effect([self.ui.frame_render])
```

**Main.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QVBoxLayout,QGraphicsDropShadowEffect,QWidget,QLabel
from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from new_ui import Ui_MainWindow

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QMainWindow,self).__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
            

        frame_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.ui.frame_render.setLayout(frame_layout)

        frame_layout.addWidget(self.show_render())
        

        self.shadow_effect([self.ui.frame_render])

    
        
    def show_render(self):

        graphics_render = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(parent=self.ui.frame_render)
        # Some URL
        graphics_render.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.youtube.com/"))
       
        return graphics_render
        
    
    def shadow_effect(self,widgets=[],blur=25,xofset=-2,yofset=-2):
        for w in widgets:
            effect = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(w)
            effect.setBlurRadius(blur)
            effect.setXOffset(xofset)
            effect.setYOffset(yofset)
            w.setGraphicsEffect(effect)



app = QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.show()
app.exec_()
```

**new_ui.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.stackedWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 0, 741, 511))
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        self.page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page.setObjectName("page")
        self.frame_render = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.page)
        self.frame_render.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 20, 381, 201))
        self.frame_render.setStyleSheet("background:white;\n"
"border-radius:50px;")
        self.frame_render.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_render.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_render.setObjectName("frame_render")
        self.frame_one = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.page)
        self.frame_one.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 300, 401, 211))
        self.frame_one.setStyleSheet("background:red;")
        self.frame_one.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_one.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_one.setObjectName("frame_one")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-40, 110, 631, 261))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../../Pictures/wallpapersden.com_windows-11-4k-black-blue-art_3840x2160.jpg"))
        self.label.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label.raise_()
        self.frame_render.raise_()
        self.frame_one.raise_()
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page)
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
```

How can I apply the `QDropShadowEffect` on the QFrame without it affecting the behavior of the `QWebEngineView`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with pygal, but it certainly is **not** the cause of the problem. I cannot ignore some important issues in your codes, though: 1. it seems you are not using [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html); 2. the border radius is obviously too big (if you properly use a layout manager as written above, you can set its contents margins accordingly); 3. setting instance attributes in a for loop (as you do with `self.effect`) is almost always completely pointless. Can you please reduce your code to a basic, *valid* [mre], which considers the above and won't include pygal)?

Comment: @musicamante
But if I don't include the pygame library, how can I reproduce the error if that's where it appears?

Comment: @musicamante, I have reformulated the question and apparently the Qwebengineview element is the one that freezes if the dropshadow effect is applied to the frame

Comment: That's exactly what I pointed above. The issue has absolutely nothing to do with pygal, since it doesn't directly have any effect on Qt: it just returns a base64 encoded SVG image that is then rendered as an encoded URI by the web engine. That said, QWebEngineView actually embeds a [QOpenGLWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html) in order to show web contents, which doesn't play well with the raster engine that is used when drawing widgets with QGraphicsEffects. Long story short: you cannot use graphics effects with a QWebEngineView.

Comment: As said, I'm not familiar with pygal, so I don't know if it also provides user interaction or just shows static content. In the latter case, the only solution you have is to grab a screenshot of the resulting page (see [this post](//stackoverflow.com/a/57957423)) and show it in a QLabel added to a QScrollArea. Otherwise, AFAIK, there's no way to do that, and you can only show the view without any effect at all. Maybe there's some way of achieving some middle ground (with Selenium and a complex system of user interaction communication) but that would be an *extremely* long shot.